# How to post HTTP request with Arduino + ESP8266 AT commands

Tags: arduino, at-command, esp8266

In order to send data to google spreadsheet I need to request HTTP access to the unique URL, something like this:

`https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz7jkkd7nfa6ThjOqGw5KZgnUUxIOrxCV_m8WithLQD4EAS7hx6/exec?SOMEDATEHERE`

I tried with:

`GET https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz7jkkd7nfa6ThjOqGw5KZgnUUxIOrxCV_m8WithLQD4EAS7hx6/exec?SOMEDATEHERE HTTP/1.0`,

but with no success.

Any idea how to execute this HTTP request with AT Commands?

Comment: You say with no success, what was the result?

Comment: This is the whole process, and even I get "SEND OK" as a result, but no new data appears in Google Spreadsheet: [link](http://image.prntscr.com/image/cb6d726f8f644e6b83f84bde334ecf7f.png)

Comment: What was the actual reply from the web?

Comment: I only get SEND OK and nothing else. If I wait for to long I get disconnected.

Comment: You can't use HTTPS with AT commands.

Answer (score 6):

I manage to do it.

First of all I wasn't able to make it work with Arduino IDE Serial Monitor because of Carriage Return and New Line characters so I switched to RealTerm. In it I manually write "\r\n" after every AT command. New i connected Googles Spreadsheet link with Pushingbox (as shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVBqUeksR1I) video). After that I used next AT commands:

```
// Only after Restarting module
//-----------------------------
AT+CIPMODE=0\r\n

AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n
//-----------------------------

AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","api.pushingbox.com",80\r\n

AT+CIPSEND=4,89\r\n

GET /pushingbox?devid=<DevID>&<field>=<value> HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.pushingbox.com\r\n\r\n
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Dude thank you so much for leaving this notes! The \r\n and HOST at the end definitely worked lol